# How to concatenate column repetitions of a matrix without a for loop

Tags: r, matrix, concatenation

Let's say I have the below matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4
[3,]    5    6
```

I want to generate a matrix which is the concatenation (by column) of matrices that are generated by repetition of each column `k` times. For example, when `k=3`, below is what I want to get:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    1    2    2    2
[2,]    3    3    3    4    4    4
[3,]    5    5    5    6    6    6
```

How can I do that **without a for loop**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with column indexing. A convenient way to repeat each column number the correct number of times is the `rep` function:

```
mat[,rep(seq_len(ncol(mat)), each=3)]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    1    1    2    2    2
# [2,]    3    3    3    4    4    4
# [3,]    5    5    5    6    6    6
```

In the above expression, `seq_len(ncol(mat))` is the sequence from 1 through the number of columns in the matrix (you could think of it like `1:ncol(mat)`, except it deals nicely with some special cases like 0-column matrices).

Data:

```
(mat <- matrix(1:6, nrow=3, byrow = TRUE))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    2
# [2,]    3    4
# [3,]    5    6
```

Answer (score 2):

We can repeat each element of matrix `k` times and fit the vector in a matrix where number of columns is `k` times the original one.

```
k <- 3
matrix(rep(t(mat), each = k), ncol = ncol(mat) * k, byrow = TRUE)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    1    1    1    2    2    2
#[2,]    3    3    3    4    4    4
#[3,]    5    5    5    6    6    6
```